# Task.GetAwaiter().GetResult() или Task.Result

Tags: c#

Вопрос такой: Почему надо использовать один способ и почему нельзя использовать другой?

На [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.tasks.task.getawaiter(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1) пишут:

> Этот метод в первую очередь предназначен для использования компилятором, а не для использования в коде приложения.

Но покопавшись в интернете нашёл, что `Task.Result` исключения оборачивает в `AggregateException` - это вся разница о которой пишут.

Хотелось бы узнать эту тему глубже.
Если будет официальная литература в которой объясняется этот вопрос - буду только рад увидеть её здесь!

Comment: Там говорится _"This method is intended for compiler use rather than for use in application code."_

Comment: @Qwertiy, неправильный перевод?

Comment: https://translate.google.com/#en/ru/rather%20than - Я бы перевёл как-то так: "Этот метод в первую очередь предназначен для использования компилятором, а не программистом".

Comment: @Qwertiy, согласен. Поправил вопрос

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Замечание, на которое вы ссылаетесь, рекомендует не работать с awaiter'ом напрямую, а использовать `await`.

Конструкция `await` использует `GetAwaiter` «под капотом». Но она, в отличие от вашего кода, получает результат асинхронно.

Синхронное получение асинхронного результата опасно, и если не на все 100% представляете себе все тонкости происходящего — вы на верном пути к deadlock'у. В качестве примера, давайте рассмотрим вот такой код:

```
async Task<int> GetOneAsync()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    return 1;
}
```

```
int one = GetOneAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Если вы выполните это в UI-потоке, возникнет deadlock. Видите, почему? `Task`, возвращаемый из `GetOneAsync`, ожидает окончания таймаута, после чего собирается вернуться в UI-поток, чтобы выполнить  `return 1;`. Но `GetResult()` блокирует UI-поток до получения результата! Таким образом, в функции `GetOneAsync` возврат в UI-поток никогда не произойдёт.

Прямой вызов `GetResult()` не приводит к проблемам в некоторых случаях — например, в случае, если `Task` уже завершён. Вот эту самую проверку компилятор делает, так что его вызов `GetResult` более безопасен.

Резюмируя: прямая работа с awaiter'ом чревата ошибками. Поэтому рекомендуется не работать с awaiter'ом вручную, а использовать `await`.

---

А использование `Task.Result` настолько же опасно, как и `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`. Старайтесь не использовать ни первое, ни второе.

Comment: Хм.. Вроде просили их между собой сравнить?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Deadlock - штука опасная, но от него можно избавиться добавив `ConfigureAwait(false)`, что не является панацеей, конечно. Саму суть TAP я понимаю. Но всё же, если каким-то образом надо синхронно выполнить операцию, то какой способ выбрать?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Не, ТС думал, что советуют использовать вместо одного другое. А по сути, советуют не пользоваться синхронным ожиданием и не работать с awaiter'ом вручную.

Comment: Ну может и так, но всё-таки можешь сравнить?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Сравнение в последнем абзаце. Краткая выдержка: один хрен.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Да, есть какие-то различия. Но это всё равно, что обсуждать, нужно ли совать в розетку пальцы левой руки, или правой. Ответ — не суйте пальцы в розетку вообще.

Comment: @Chloroform: Для начала, `ConfigureAwait(false)` — не панацея (например, потому, что это заклинание **не** перебрасывает выполнение в фоновый поток). Во-вторых, если вам нужна синхронная операция, почему бы не воспользоваться синхронным API? Или наоборот, если у вас асинхронное API, почему бы не использовать его асинхронным образом? В общем случае вы не знаете, какие потоки нужно разблокировать, чтобы асинхронное API сработало. И вы не знаете, как устроена асинхронная функция внутри.

Comment: @VladD, идёт переезд синхронной API на асинхронную, есть некоторые места, где используется приведение к синхронной модели, вот и возник подобный вопрос. Если `Task.Result` реально использует под капотом `Task.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` и просто оборачивает исключения - то в принципе у вас достаточный ответ.

Comment: @Chloroform: Если это временный код, до полной асинхронизации, то вполне можно использовать любой из них. Возможны дэдлоки, но это временный баг на время переезда.

Comment: @Chloroform: `Task.Result` не вызывает под капотом `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`, но они делают внутри практически одно и то же ([(1)](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Future.cs,e1c63c9e90fb2f26), [(2)](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs,aa2362a27deccda6)).

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендуют использовать такой подход.

```
var value = Task.Run(async () => await GetValueAsync()).Result;
```