# Оптимизировать объемный код вывода в TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, инспекция-кода

Прошу Вас помочь оптимизировать код вывода в textblock. Показать как правильно. Спасибо.

```
public void PrintCurrentlyPlaying(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var sessionManager = GlobalSystemMediaTransportControlsSessionManager.RequestAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult(); // получаем результат из Control Media Windows 10
        if (sessionManager != null) // если результат получен, то 
        {
            var currentSession = sessionManager.GetCurrentSession(); // возращаем сессию
            if (currentSession != null) // если сессия не пустая, то
            {
                var mediaProperties = currentSession.TryGetMediaPropertiesAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult(); // в mediaProperties мы отправляем название воспроизведения и имя автора
                if (unknown_artist.IsChecked == true && dash_instead_text.IsChecked == false && mediaProperties.Artist == "Неизвестный исполнитель") // проверяем настройки приложения и выводим со словами
                    compocition_output.Text = $"Проигрывается: {mediaProperties.Title}";
                else
                {
                    if (unknown_artist.IsChecked == true && dash_instead_text.IsChecked == true && mediaProperties.Artist == "Неизвестный исполнитель") // иначе выводим без слов
                        compocition_output.Text = $"{mediaProperties.Title}";
                    else
                    {
                        if (dash_instead_text.IsChecked == true && mediaProperties.Artist != "")  
                            compocition_output.Text = $"{mediaProperties.Title} - {mediaProperties.Artist}";
                        else 
                        {
                            if (dash_instead_text.IsChecked == true)
                                compocition_output.Text = $"{mediaProperties.Title}";
                            else
                            {
                                if (mediaProperties.Artist != "")
                                {
                                    if (author_checkbox.IsChecked == true && compocition_checkbox.IsChecked == true)
                                        compocition_output.Text = $"Проигрывается: {mediaProperties.Title}, от автора: {mediaProperties.Artist}";
                                    else
                                    {
                                        if (author_checkbox.IsChecked == false && compocition_checkbox.IsChecked == true)
                                            compocition_output.Text = $"Проигрывается: {mediaProperties.Title}";
                                        else
                                        {
                                            if (author_checkbox.IsChecked == true && compocition_checkbox.IsChecked == false)
                                                compocition_output.Text = $"Автор воспроизведения: {mediaProperties.Artist}";
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                    compocition_output.Text = $"Проигрывается: {mediaProperties.Title}";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
                compocition_output.Text = "Упс... А музыка у нас закончилась!";
        }
        else
            compocition_output.Text = "Упс... А музыка у нас закончилась!";
        if (output_file_checkbox.IsChecked == true)
        {
            file_save(null, null); // сохраняем название в .txt файл
        }

    }
```

Если будет возможно с комментариями.

Comment: А что понимается под словом «оптимизировать»? Если уменьшить количество кода, то начните с устранения копипасты. Смотрите на повторяющиеся строки кода, обобщите их. Кстати, это WPF?

Comment: Этот код работает?

Comment: Может стоило хотя бы написать, что вообще этот код делает?

Comment: @АртёмОконечников, да это WPF. Первое приложение. Без ООП, из-за не знания соответственно(видно по коду). Проблема еще тут в том, что я немного не понимаю, где копипаст.

Comment: @aepot Наверное к вашему сожалению - да

Comment: @ПавелЕриков этот код берет MediaControlCenter информацию о воспроизводимой композиции. Проверяет через несколько заданных правил и отправляет в textblock и .txt файл. Уточню в вопросе. Спасибо, что подсказали.

Comment: @ArtemL. там в ответах уже рассказали о копипасте. Самое главное тут, мне кажется, что большинство вещей (форматы, строки, некоторые проверки и т.д.) можно выполнить в XAML на стороне представления. Вам нужно разделить понятия поставищика данных и представления этих данных. Попробуйте прочитать о MVVM-шаблоне.

Comment: @АртёмОконечников я первый раз использую WPF. Вы можете подсказать, что можно выполнить в XALM*?

Comment: Для знакомства с WPF и XAML, попробуйте почитать и разобрать [этот пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1222168/373567).

Comment: @aepot извините, а почему пропал Ваш ответ?

Comment: Ну вы приняли другой ответ, я удалил как бесполезный. Если вам что-то еще из него надо, восстановил, простите.

Comment: @aepot Ваш ответ очень полезный лично для меня. Прямо по нему, сейчас изучаю аспекты некоторые аспекты программирования. Тот ответ, я отметил как лучший, так как он более оптимизирован. Вдруг, в будущем, кто-то будет искать как коротко оптимизировать и наткнётся на этот ответ. На данный момент, убрал отметку, т.к оба ответа, являются великолепными. Спасибо Вам, Вы мне действительно помогли разобраться!

Comment: @ArtemL. оптимизирован или код короче? Код короче - да, но фактически быстрее (хоть и незначительно) по производительности работать будет мой вариант. Но вам виднее, ок, если считаете полезным - оставлю ответ. А метку поставьте куда-нибудь, иначе вопрос будет считаться неотвеченным.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Добро пожаловать в [Асинхронное программирование](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async). Если вы используете `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`, либо вы абсолютно точно уверены, что вы знаете, что делаете, либо что-то пошло не так, например вы не в курсе о существовании `async/await`. Нужно использовать `await`.
2. Есть такая проверка на `null` - [NULL-условный оператор](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) `?.`. Познакомьтесь с ним, очень сильно упрощает код в некоторых местах.
3. У вас повторяется код, вы одно и то же условие перепроверяете по многу раз. Чтобы одно и то же перезаписать в текстовое поле. Вам по сути нужно построить строчку из кусочков, исходя из разных условий. Отлично! Для этого есть замечательный класс `StringBuilder`, к тому же он работает намного быстрее, чем интерполяция или конкатенация строк.
4. `if (b == true)` можно заменить на `if (b)`, а `if (b == false)` можно заменить на `if (!b)`, потому что логическое выражение и так само по себе `true` или `false` и преобразовывать например `true` в `true` с помощью проверки на `true` - излишество.
5. `text != ""` можно записать как `text.Length > 0`, ну потому что это технически работает быстрее. Так как числовые операции всегда быстрее строковых.

Вот моя попытка подчистить код согласно выше изложенному, но наверняка это еще можно улучшить.

```cs
public async void PrintCurrentlyPlaying(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // в async void методах обязательно нужно обрабатывать все возможные исключения, иначе вы их просто не увидите, а работать не будет
    try
    {
        var sessionManager = await GlobalSystemMediaTransportControlsSessionManager.RequestAsync();
        var currentSession = sessionManager?.GetCurrentSession();
        if (currentSession != null)
        {
            var mediaProperties = await currentSession.TryGetMediaPropertiesAsync();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            if (unknown_artist.IsChecked && mediaProperties.Artist == "Неизвестный исполнитель")
            {
                if (!dash_instead_text.IsChecked)
                    sb.Append("Проигрывается: ");
                sb.Append(mediaProperties.Title);
            }
            else
            {
                if (dash_instead_text.IsChecked)
                {
                    sb.Append(mediaProperties.Title);
                    if (mediaProperties.Artist.Length > 0)
                        sb.Append(" - ").Append(mediaProperties.Artist);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (mediaProperties.Artist.Length > 0)
                    {
                        if (compocition_checkbox.IsChecked)
                        {
                            sb.Append("Проигрывается: ").Append(mediaProperties.Title);
                            if (author_checkbox.IsChecked)
                                sb.Append(", от автора: ").Append(mediaProperties.Artist);
                        }
                        else
                            sb.Append("Автор воспроизведения: ").Append(mediaProperties.Artist);
                    }
                    else
                        sb.Append("Проигрывается: ").Append(mediaProperties.Title); ;
                }
            }
            compocition_output.Text = sb.ToString();
        }
        else
            compocition_output.Text = "Упс... А музыка у нас закончилась!";
        if (output_file_checkbox.IsChecked)
        {
            file_save(null, null);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: В строке  `var currentSession = sessionManager?.GetCurrentSession();` зачем вы прописываете знак вопроса?
`.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` брал из шаблона. Поэтому так и оставил. В чем проблема? Просто понять никак не могу. Почему await?

Comment: @ArtemL. Любопытно вы читаете что вам пишут, ибо в пункте 2 этого ответа сказано "зачем". А про `async` - можно и [поискать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/793369/220553).

Comment: @ArtemL. про знак вопрос - пункт 2, про `await` - очень долгая история, связанная с понятиями Sync-over-Async и Deadlock. С чего начать знакомство с этой темой - используйте ссылку в п.1. Если не готовы разбираться, просто запомните, что `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` - это можно и нужно заменить на `async/await`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спросил по поводу знака вопроса потому, что вы в следующей же строке проверяете на null.. зачем тогда?

Comment: @ArtemL. Сколько у вас проверок на `null` и сколько у меня? Одну я заменил на `?.`.

Comment: @aepot я к сожалению так и не понял, за какую проверку в моем коде, отвечает этот `?.` Вы можете показать? Спасибо.

Comment: @ArtemL. за `if (sessionManager != null)`. Почитайте документ по ссылке из второго пункта и все станет понятно.

Comment: @aepot "`text != ""` можно записать как `text.Length > 0`" может это всё же преждевременная оптимизация? Да и в первом варианте, я думаю сравнение двух ссылок из пула интернирования не очень дорогое

Comment: @4per то что компилятор затыкает дыры в знаниях разработчика оптимизациями не значит что не стоит знать решения для общего случая. :) В любом случае, это после оптимизации через `Length` будет работать либо так же, либо быстрее, хуже точно не будет.

Comment: @aepot зато семантика страдает

Comment: @4per я не знаю, что такое семантика. Но мне жаль, что она страдает. :)

Answer (score 3):

Просто оставлю это здесь)

```
public async void PrintCurrentlyPlaying(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var currentSession = (await GlobalSystemMediaTransportControlsSessionManager.RequestAsync())?.GetCurrentSession(); // возращаем сессию
    if (currentSession != null) // если сессия не пустая, то
    {
        var mediaProperties = await currentSession.TryGetMediaPropertiesAsync(); // в mediaProperties мы отправляем название воспроизведения и имя автора
        var isUnknownArtist = mediaProperties.Artist is "" or "Неизвестный исполнитель";

        compocition_output.Text =
            (IsUnknownArtist: isUnknownArtist,
            UnknownArtistChecked: unknown_artist.IsChecked,
            DashInsteadText: dash_instead_text.IsChecked,
            IsAuthor: author_checkbox.IsChecked,
            IsCompocition: compocition_checkbox.IsChecked) switch
            {
                { UnknownArtistChecked: true, DashInsteadText: true, IsUnknownArtist: true } => $"{mediaProperties.Title}",
                { DashInsteadText: true, IsUnknownArtist: false } => $"{mediaProperties.Title} - {mediaProperties.Artist}",
                { DashInsteadText: true, IsUnknownArtist: true } => $"{mediaProperties.Title}",
                { IsUnknownArtist: false, IsAuthor: true, IsCompocition: true } => $"Проигрывается: {mediaProperties.Title}, от автора: {mediaProperties.Artist}",
                { IsUnknownArtist: false, IsAuthor: true, IsCompocition: false } => $"Автор воспроизведения: {mediaProperties.Artist}",
                _ => $"Проигрывается: {mediaProperties.Title}"
            };
    }
    else
        compocition_output.Text = "Упс... А музыка у нас закончилась!";

    if (output_file_checkbox.IsChecked == true)
        file_save(null, null); // сохраняем название в .txt файл
}
```

<sup>Не проверял, да и уверен, что накосячил с некоторыми проверками, там уже если нужно будет, подправите под себя.</sup>

Весьма забавно было такое сжимать и сокращать. Вообще, вся ваша проблема в том, что... У вас много проблем, ибо у вас и UI используется как источник хранения данных и все смешано в одну кашу, попробуйте это разделить на отдельный, мало связанные друг с другом куски, тогда будет проще.

Из кода выше можно заметить, что некоторые проверки весьма странные и лишние, да и вообще не пойму зачем такая "динамика" в название, обычно это четко сформированный стандарт (аля: `автор - трек`), а остальное это "рюшечки" UI, может вам стоит пойти именно по этому пути?

Также из замечаний, почему метод `PrintCurrentlyPlaying` вдруг отвечает за сохранение? `Print` это вывести, а не сохранить.

Ну и про всякие `async` и прочее вам уже сказали другим ответом.

---

В моем примере используется последняя версия языка (C#9), можно без проблем опустить до C#8, заменив

```
var isUnknownArtist = mediaProperties.Artist is "" or "Неизвестный исполнитель";
```

на

```
var isUnknownArtist = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mediaProperties.Artist) || mediaProperties.Artist == "Неизвестный исполнитель";
```

Ниже C#8 работать не будет, ибо все эти навороты с `switch` появились в нем (хотя кто знает, может умельцы сделали стороннюю библиотеку).

Comment: метод PrintCurrentlyPlaying был взят из шаблона и просто немного доработался моими кривыми руками.

Comment: @ArtemL. Шаблоны и инструкции зачастую делаются упрощенными, не нагруженными всякими паттернами и прочим. Например, если у вас WPF, то там используются привязки, а это значит, что вместо `unknown_artist.IsChecked` (обращения к UI) у вас должен быть класс с нужными свойствами, например класс "Информация трека", который содержит в себе свойства "Автор", "Название", "Тип трека", "Дата" и др. и уже с ним вы работаете. Также все ваши настройки, они должны быть в отдельном классе в виде простых свойств, а не в UI. Запомните простое правило - UI - это лишь взаимодействие с пользователем, не более.

Comment: C# 9 же? Быть может стоит пометить, что этот код требует .NET 5?

Comment: @aepot Не, 8-го достаточно должно быть.

Comment: `or` - это точно девятый.

Comment: @aepot Ай, по привычки уже пишу это. Добавил, что на что заменить, остальное точно 8-й.